# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS magento 2.1

Tags: admin, error

I cannot access the Admin panel, I'm getting error **`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`**. I try replace **localhost** to **`127.0.0.1`** in base url, clean cache, cookies, there is **no underscore** in **url** and **frontend** working fine. 
Please help me to resolve the issue. Is there any way to change cookies configuration in **`store/general/web`** with **`PhpMyAdmin`**?